# How does @Inject in java work?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I was playing with how to use dependency injection, and figured out instead of using

```
public class AnyClass{ 

    public void AnyMethod(){

       Foo foo =  new Foo(); //instantiated new class
        out.println(foo.bar()); //printed arbitrary anything! out is printwriter 
    }

}
```

Let the container handle so that I could just write my code. So, I decided to use.

```
public class AnyClass{

@Inject Foo foo;

public void anyMethod(){

    out.println(foo.getMyName()); //doesn't work here!!

}
```

I must have done something wrong in using @Inject correctly. But, after looking at many books and tutorials, I couldn't figure out where. Here's what I did.

1. used NetBeans to build beans.xml file in WEB-INF of my project, didn't work!
2. Looked at a book and they said to keep it on META-INF, didn't work either!
3. Tried to stick it with @Qualifiers, by describing

   ```
   @inferface MyQualify //or sth!!
   ```

   which didn't work, and therefore, Foo was a class that didn't implement any interface. So, I assumed it was wrong, and it didn't work either.
4. Some tutorials suggested to annotate Java Class (here Foo) with @ManagedBean, which didn't work either.

And, I am using TOMCAT 8, and NetBeans.

Comment: You would need to declare `Foo` as a managed bean. Have you done that? Show that please.

Comment: it didn't work that way either.

Comment: Tomcat 8 is not a Java EE compatible server, its a servlet container. What are you using to provide CDI capabilities?

Comment: Just default java ee package installed on my computer.

Comment: What? You are making very little sense here. You are not posting any errors. You are not posting any configuration. And Tomcat has no CDI capability, unless you have (for example) Weld installed you _have_ no CDI. Please take some time to clarify this question.

Comment: @Rockink Have you added any dependency injection framework? Like Spring, Guice or Weld?

Comment: Spring framework worked out. Thanks